# Differential Query : how to distinguish change from creation

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I use Azure AD Graph API differential query to detect changes in my Azure AD.

For each result node of type `User` or `Group` how can I distinguish if the object is new or only updated?

I use the `ocp-aad-dq-include-only-changed-properties` option to obtain only the changed properties. But what happens if all the properties have been changed? I received all the properties as if the object is new.

Answer (score 2):

You have to save all existing objects in a storage, then when a change occurs, check if the storage contains this object and update the storage (add or delete the changed object if needed)

This is the only way I found on my research. If you find more simle solution, please post it here as an answer

Comment: Unfortunately I fear it is the only solution. 
That said, no need to retain all the properties of the object. The attribute `objectId` (the primary key) is enough to detect it already exists.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. Only need to keep properties if you want to get previous value of the attribute being changed

Comment: I just posted an [idea for the Azure AD team](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16723471-graph-api-differential-query-need-a-way-to-distin).

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Azure (but familiar with AD).

Some attributes can't be change once created, but must be set on creation.
e.g. objectCategory

So if it exists in result -> creation.
Not exist -> update.

One case I am not sure about is the **deletion** case.
Depending whether Recycle Bin feature is enabled (do Azure have this?), objectCategory may be cleared on deletion. 
Sorry, I will leave this for you to test.

Comment: Deletion is indicated by the attribute `aad.isDeleted`. I did not identify specific attribute to the creation event. Azure AD seems different from AD!